# Visual Studio 2022 : Console template has .NET 5 as current

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2022

On my post, I used Visual Studio 2019, but recently I installed in addition Visual Studio 2022.

In Visual Studio 2022, when I create a new console project ("Console App" template), by default the selected target framework is .NET 5 :
[image]

Moreover, .NET 5 is marked as "(Current)" when .NET 6 is installed :

```
> dotnet --info
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   6.0.200
 Commit:    4c30de7899

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.14393
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.200\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 6.0.2
  Commit:  839cdfb0ec

.NET SDKs installed:
  2.1.526 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.602 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.700 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.811 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.2.402 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  3.0.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  3.1.120 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  3.1.408 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  5.0.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  5.0.405 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  6.0.200 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.18 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.23 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.30 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.18 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.23 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.30 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.14 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.20 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.22 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.14 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.18 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.23 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.30 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.14 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.20 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.22 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.14 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.14 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.20 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.22 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.14 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
```

Often I create new console project to do some test. Each time, I need to select ".NET 6.0" (when I don't forget) to use the latest functionality. It's distasteful.

How configure VS 2022 to have .NET by default in the target framework combo box?

Optionally, what do mean "Current"?

Comment: Very similar to the final version of [.NET 6.0 not showing in Visual Studio 2022 (General Release)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69927947/215552), enough that I think that the answer there will work for you.

Comment: You might also take a look at [this GitHub list of known .NET 6 issues](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/main/release-notes/6.0/known-issues.md#2-upgrade-of-visual-studio-or-net-sdk-from-earlier-builds-can-result-in-a-bad-path-configuration-on-windows).

Answer (score 1):

@HereticMonkey, thank you for showing me the light.

The computer has two install of dotnet :

- C:\Program Files\dotnet
- C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet

The x86 cli give a different result :

```
>"C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\dotnet.exe" --info
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   5.0.100-preview.7.20366.6
 Commit:    0684df3a5b

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.14393
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x86
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk\5.0.100-preview.7.20366.6\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 6.0.2
  Commit:  839cdfb0ec

.NET SDKs installed:
  5.0.100-preview.7.20366.6 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.22 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.0-preview.7.20365.19 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.14 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.2 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.22 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.0-preview.7.20364.11 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.14 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.2 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.22 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.0-preview.7.20366.1 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.14 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.2 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

To install additional .NET runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

With the tool [dotnet-core-uninstall](https://github.com/dotnet/cli-lab) tool, I list all SDKs :

```
>dotnet-core-uninstall list

This tool cannot uninstall versions of the runtime or SDK that are 
    - SDKs installed using Visual Studio 2019 Update 3 or later.
    - SDKs and runtimes installed via zip/scripts.
    - Runtimes installed with SDKs (these should be removed by removing that SDK).
The versions that can be uninstalled with this tool are:

.NET Core SDKs:
  5.0.100-preview.7.20366.6  x86
  5.0.100                    x64    [Used by Visual Studio. Specify individually or use --force to remove]
  3.1.408                    x64
  3.1.120                    x64
  3.0.100                    x64
  2.2.402                    x64    [Used by Visual Studio 2019. Specify individually or use --force to remove]
  2.1.811                    x64    [Used by Visual Studio 2019. Specify individually or use --force to remove]
  2.1.700                    x64
  2.1.602                    x64
  2.1.526                    x64    [Used by Visual Studio 2017. Specify individually or use --force to remove]

.NET Core Runtimes:

ASP.NET Core Runtimes:

.NET Core Runtime & Hosting Bundles:
```

The x86 come from a preview version... Like explained in this link [.NET known-issues](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/main/release-notes/6.0/known-issues.md#2-upgrade-of-visual-studio-or-net-sdk-from-earlier-builds-can-result-in-a-bad-path-configuration-on-windows).

> When upgrading Visual Studio to preview 5 or the .NET SDK to RC2 from an earlier build, the installer will uninstall the prior version of the .NET Host (dotnet.exe) and then install a new version. This results in the path to the x64 copy of dotnet being removed from the PATH then added back. If you have the x86 .NET Host installed, it will end up ahead of the x64 one and will be picked up first.

...

> To fix this, edit your PATH environment variable to either remove the c:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet entry or move it after the entry for c:\Program Files\dotnet. Now reopen your console window.

I remove all x86 entries (only 5.0.100-preview.7.20366.6 in my case) :

```
>dotnet-core-uninstall remove --sdk 5.0.100-preview.7.20366.6
The following items will be removed:
  Microsoft .NET SDK 5.0.100-preview.7.20366.6 (x86)

To avoid breaking Visual Studio or other problems, read https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-uninstall-docs.

Do you want to continue? [y/n] y
Uninstalling: Microsoft .NET SDK 5.0.100-preview.7.20366.6 (x86).

The folder "C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet" has been removed.
```

Now, when I create a new console project in Visual Studio 2022, the target framework .NET 6 is selected by default.